# opening an HTML file with a link

Tags: html, directory

to try and keep brief,
I have an HTML code as my main page that is located inside folder A.
inside of folder A, are 2 things, mainwebsite.html and folder B.
inside of folder B, I have another HTML file that I would like to open with chrome.

so something like this

- folder A

  -mainwebsite.html

  -folder B

  - other.html

so inside mainwebsite.html I want to have a link that opens other.html,
how do i

1. get the link to be able to open an HTML file
2. open said HTML file in another directory without having to specify the C drive (for example if i wanted to move folder A)

Comment: `<a href="folderB/other.html">link</a>`  The search term for more information about how this works is "relative paths"

Comment: When folder B is inside folder A: `<a href="folderB/other.html">click here</a>`

Comment: yep, I misread the question at first, thanks @Calaris

Comment: Ya ive tried that but chrome returns with a file not found, i believe it has to do with security? Something along the lines of <a herf="file\\\folder B/other.html">link</a> but it returns with the same result

Comment: You should open your other.html in chrome and copy that address into your first file link. As it looks like you have inserted wrong address. For e.g. file:///home/myLinux/Desktop/i.html

Comment: Don't include the "file://" in the URL; that turns it back into an absolute path (to the filesystem, which means it also won't work when put online.)  Put it exactly as was shown in the first two comments. No protocol, just `href="folderB/other.html"`.

Comment: it works now, i could have sworn that i did that and it didnt work, but thank you.